# What is wrong in my query with MySql store procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am new to mysql store procedure. I want my store procedure to check date value in Field date and compare to current date. If current date is bigger than date value in table, I want to update value in field status_number to '0'.

Here is my query :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS check_status$$
CREATE PROCEDURE check_status()

 BEGIN
     DECLARE dd DATE;
     DECLARE bDone INT;
     DECLARE Count INT;
     DEClARE my_status CURSOR FOR SELECT dates FROM t_date;
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

 OPEN my_status;
    SET bDone = 0;

    REPEAT
        FETCH my_status INTO dd;

        IF (dd < DATE(NOW()))

                UPDATE t_date SET (status_number) VALUES (1);

        END IF;

    UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

 CLOSE my_status;


 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error message :

[image]

Thank for answering.

Comment: Every if must have a then

Answer (score 0):

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS check_status$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE check_status()

     BEGIN
         DECLARE dd DATE;
         DECLARE bDone INT;
         DECLARE Count INT;
         DEClARE my_status CURSOR FOR SELECT dates FROM t_date;
         DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

     OPEN my_status;
        SET bDone = 0;

        REPEAT
            FETCH my_status INTO dd;

            IF (dd < DATE(NOW()))
--                  UPDATE t_date SET (status_number) VALUES (1);
                    UPDATE t_date SET status_number =  1;

            END IF;

        UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

     CLOSE my_status;


     END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Every if must have a then

Answer (score 0):

Check it. its tested on mssql. I try to convert it for mysql but not tested on mysql but i hope it will works.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE check_status()

BEGIN
DECLARE NOT_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE v_dd DATE;
-- DECLARE @bDone INT;
-- DECLARE @Count INT;


DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(50); -- database name 
DECLARE v_path VARCHAR(256); -- path for backup files 
DECLARE v_fileName VARCHAR(256); -- filename for backup 
DECLARE v_fileDate VARCHAR(20); -- used for file name 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECTdates INTO v_dd 
FROM t_date

OPEN 
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET NOT_FOUND = 1;db_cursor  
 -- SET @bDone = 0;
FETCH NEXT FROM; db_cursor INTO v_dd  

WHILE NOT_FOUND = 0  
DO  

        IF (v_dd < cast (Now() as date) )
        Then
                    UPDATE t_date SET status_number   =  1;
        END IF; 

      FETCH NEXT FROM; db_cursor INTO v_dd  
END WHILE; 

CLOSE db_cursor;  
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```